# Match String with List Items

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a list and two strings :

```
 val features = List("one","two","three")
 val strOne = "one_five"
 val strTwo = "seven_five"
```

I'd like to match each string to items of the list.

If beginning of string matches one of list items then print matched list item and string itself.

If not, nothing to print.

I have method that I think make what I need but I cannot compile it  :

```
def getElement(any: String): String = any match {
  case s :: rest if features.contains(s) => s + "= " + any
  case _ => // Nothing 
}
```

I wanted the following :

```
   scala> getElement(strOne)
          "one_five= one"

   scala> getElement(strTwo)
```

Comment: Pattern matching is not string matching or matching patterns in a string.

Comment: Got your point, 10x

Comment: @Toren `def getElement(str: String): String = features.find(_ == str.split("_")(0)).map { elem => s"$str= $elem"}.getOrElse("")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple one line Scala code**

Find in list the item who's first part is present in the list

```
features.find(_ == str.split("_")(0)).map { elem => s"$str= $elem"}.getOrElse("")
```

Put the above line inside the function.

```
def getElement(str: String): String = features.find(_ == str.split("_")(0)).map { elem => s"$str= $elem"}.getOrElse("")
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala>  val strOne = "one_five"
strOne: String = one_five

scala>  val str = "one_five"
str: String = one_five

scala> features.find(_ == str.split("_")(0)).getOrElse("")
res2: String = one

scala> features.find(_ == str.split("_")(0)).map(elem => s"$str= $elem").getOrElse("")
res3: String = one_five= one
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Actually strOne looks like `strOne = "one_one_five_1_2_3"` and  features `val features = List("one_one","two_two","three_three")` . Sorry , it was not clear from my side . And another question : what happened if I have a list of strings to check opposite the `features` list ?

Comment: @Toren  which part of `strOne` do you want to compare ? Out of `one_one_five_1_2_3`. If you want to compare only first `one` then my code works

Comment: I'd like to compare begging of `strOne` and `strTwo` to each one of `features` if match , then construct expression

Answer (score 3):

You can't just return nothing. You promised that your method would return a `String`, so you *must* return one. You can either return an `Option[String]` (preferred) or return `Unit` and do the printing yourself. Further, the built in method `TraversableLike#find` will do part of the job.

```
def findFeature(str: String): Option[String] = features.find(_ startsWith str) map { value => s"$str=$value" }
```

In order to get the printing behavior:

```
findFeature(str) foreach println
// or redefine findFeature similarly
```

Further, you seem to misunderstand pattern matching: You don't want to match on the string; you want to match the list's elements *against* the string. Here's a version that uses pattern matching:

```
def getElement(feature: String): Option[String] = {
  @tailrec def getElem0(feature: String, strs: List[String]): Option[String] = strs match {
    case s :: _ if s startsWith feature => Some(s"$feature=$s") // Matching case
    case _ :: rest => getElem0(feature, rest) // Not matched, but more to search
    case Nil => None // Empty list; failure
  }
  getElem0(feature, features)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution can't compile because `::` is a `List` method, and `s` is a String. Moreover, `getElement` is declared to return a `String` therefore it should return a String for *any* input. So you can't just return "nothing" in the second case.

Here's an alternative implementation:

```
def printElement(any: String): Unit = features
  .find(s => any.startsWith(s)) // find matching (returns Option[String])
  .foreach(s => println(s + "= "+ any))  // print if found

printElement(strOne) // one= one_five
printElement(strTwo)
```

Comment: `::` is a case class. Unfairly, you can `'a' +: "bc"` but not `s match { case 'a' +: "bc" => }`. Anyway strings can be viewed as `Seq[Char]`.

Comment: @tzach-zohar . Thanks ! I prefer to return String , I'd like to create SparkSQL expression after finding elements , but I got your point